# AEM CQ- nested multifield component, the nested fields starting with 2 text boxes by default

Tags: nested, components, default, aem

I am using AEM 6.1, building a nested multifield component in classic. However, I want the nested multifield (the one inside) to start with 2 text boxes and at every addition, it needs to add 2 more.

I am using the nested multifield implementation from

https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/nested_multifield.html

Has anyone tried this? Please do let me know

Thanks!

Comment: Please include the version of AEM you are using as well as the code used for your nested multifield, are you using ACS commons? Another library? your own implementation? also is it for Touch or Classic UI ?

Comment: edited my question

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the adobe article you referenced: https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/nested_multifield.html

If you want the inner multifield to have 2 fields instead of one, you have to change the multifield's `fieldConfig` from a text field:

```
fieldConfig: {
                "xtype" : "textfield",
                allowBlank: false,
             },
```

to a composite field:

```
fieldConfig: {
                "xtype" : "cq.compositefield",
                "items": [
                    { "xtype" : "textfield", allowBlank: false},
                    { "xtype" : "textfield", allowBlank: false}
                ]

            },
```

you are also going to likely have to update the `updateHidden` function to make sure you capture all the information from the new composite field.

References:
AEM 6.1 widget api for more information: https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/ref/widgets-api/index.html

multifield doc: https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/ref/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.form.MultiField

compositeField doc: https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/ref/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.form.CompositeField